# SQL Server date format yyyymmdd

Tags: sql-server, database, date, datetime, varchar

I have a `varchar` column where some values are in `mm/dd/yyyy` format and some are in `yyyymmdd`.

I want to convert all `mm/dd/yyyy` dates into the `yyyymmdd` format. What is the best way to do this? Thanks

Table is `Employees` and column is `DOB`

Comment: Actual `date`/`datetime`-valued columns don't have a format. Do you mean to say you have columns which contain textual representations of dates in `char`/`varchar` columns?

Comment: Never store date/time values in varchar columns... Use proper data types instead.

Answer (score 53):

Assuming your "date" column is not actually a date.

```
Select convert(varchar(8),cast('12/24/2016' as date),112)
```

or

```
Select format(cast('12/24/2016' as date),'yyyyMMdd')
```

Returns

```
20161224
```

Comment: Note that `FORMAT`'s performance is terrible, but there's nothing wrong with using it for scalar calls. If you're using it in a resultset that will be called many times, use `CONVERT` instead.

Comment: @DerreckDean Absolutely agree.  That's why I listed it as a second "option".  I should have expressed that more clearly.

Comment: Heh...IMHO, there is absolutely no justification for using the FORMAT function.  It's just too slow.  Justifying it for small row counts is a terrible excuse and adds to the performance "Death by a Thousand Cuts" state that a lot of servers are in. That includes "scalar calls".  if you have 10,000 of those scalar calls ever second, you'll be in deep Kimchi if you use FORMAT.  Just pretend it doesn't exist and do it with some form of CONVERT.  Even complex CONVERTs will blow the doors off of FORMAT.

Comment: @JeffModen Like I tell my kids... "never" is a really big word.  It is just an option... another tool in the belt.  That said, performance aside, there are some useful features in format.  When I do use format, I use it sparingly ... usually on final datasets.  Not every table is a billion rows and performance is not the only consideration in programming.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - I guess I'll never understand why people justify the use of known problems just because of smaller row sets.  I also agree that accuracy should always be the primary consideration but if you look at the posts of this and other forums, performance is a very close second.  Like I tell my kids, never put your hand on a hot stove. :D

Comment: @JeffModen We all have our own dogmas.  Performance is usually further down on my list...   Generally speaking, #1 is Value-Add,  #2 is data integrity and #3 will depend on the application and audience.     Your purview is not mine.  If a shortcut costs milliseconds and allows me to move on, sobeit.  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - I guess we'll have to agree to disagree, John.  Oddly enough, though, I strongly agree with the Value-add.  If it's not worth it, why work on it?

Answer (score 12):

```
DECLARE @v DATE= '3/15/2013'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @v, 112)
```

you can convert any date format or date time format to YYYYMMDD with no delimiters

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail?

Comment: Third parameter is the CONVERT() function code for DateTime to ISO
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Answer (score 7):

You can do as follows:

```
Select Format(test.Time, 'yyyyMMdd')
From TableTest test
```

Comment: this is much readable than Select `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)`. I should always have a lookup to understand what does 112 means.

Answer (score 3):

try this....

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST(DOB AS DATE),'yyyyMMdd') FROM Employees;
```

Comment: No.  Don't use FORMAT.  It's too damned slow.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)
```

Tested in SQL Server 2012

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
select coalesce(format(try_convert(date, col, 112), 'yyyyMMdd'), col)
```

This attempts the conversion, keeping the previous value if available.

Note:  I hope you learned a lesson about storing dates as dates and not strings.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  YEAR(getdate()) * 10000 + MONTH(getdate()) * 100 + DAY(getdate())

Answer (score 0):

mm/dd/yyyy corresponds to U.S. standard  so if you convert to date using 101  value and then to varchar using 112 for ISO date get the expected result.

```
declare @table table (date_value varchar(10))
insert into @table values ('03/30/2022'),('20220330')

select date_value
    --converted to varchar
    ,case 
        --mm/dd/yyyy pattern
        when patindex('[0,1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',date_value)>0 then convert(varchar(10),convert(date,date_value,101),112) 
        else date_value end date_value_new
    --converted to date
    ,case 
        when patindex('[0,1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',date_value)>0 then convert(date,date_value,101)
        else convert(date,date_value,112) end date_value_date
from @table
```

Answer (score -3):

SELECT TO_CHAR(created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM table;
//converts any date format to YYYY-MM-DD